# creating a loop to loop over the componennt created

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this data which is returning me the labels and every I need to create a component.

The component is already built when I pass the values. Now I want to create it as a for loop so that I can keep on adding entries, and it will create components as needed.

This is what I've tried:

```js
data() {
  return {
    options: [{

        heading: 'Welcome to the Card',
        subheading: 'Manage your Profile here'
      },
      {

        heading: 'Pay your bills',
        subheading: 'Manage your bills and payments here'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to loop it over like this

```html
<div v-for="(value, key) in options">
  <componentName {{key}} = {{value}}/>  
</div>
```

Previously, the above code was like this:

```html
<componentName :heading='Welcome to the Card' :subheading='Manage your Profile here'/>
```

Which works well but to add more I have to recreate this `<componentName` which I want to avoid. I want to keep one entry and feed it with array of objects

I'm using Vue2. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just a note for next time, try to follow [these good English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/979052) principles, and use [correct formatting of code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/979052) - it will make your question easier to read, and answer. But for now, I've [corrected](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72113093/revisions) the issues as an edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close. Given your data, the template would need to look like:

```html
<div v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index">
  <h3>{{ option.heading }}</h3>
  <p>{{ option.subheading}}</p>
</div>
```

Or, if you've got a custom component, which takes `heading` and `subheading` as props:

```html
<componentName
  v-for="(option, index) in options"
  :key="index"
  :heading="option.heading"
  :subheading="option.subheading"
/>
```

If you can share a bit more of your code, I can create a runnable snippet, if that would be helpful.